# Difference in behavior between two MySQL servers (Error 1292)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, logging, zend-framework

We use two servers (**devsrv** & **qualifsrv**), one for development and one for the qualification of our applications.
I have exactly the same Zend application on both servers (files and configuration of the application are the same).

I have a log table in which I insert the treatments carried out and the time required to achieve them.

When I insert a row into my table "Log" on the server **devsrv**, no problem.
When I execute exactly the same query in the table "Log" on the **qualifsrv** server, MySQL returns an error stating that in 1292 the value for the log_duration field is incorrect.

My log table :

```
CREATE TABLE `T_log` (
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `log_priority` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_priority_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_event` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_commentaire` longtext,
  `log_impacted_row` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `vag_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`),
  KEY `idx_log_priority` (`log_priority`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_log_date` (`log_date`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_log_event` (`log_event`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_impacted_row` (`log_impacted_row`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `fk_vag_id` (`vag_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `T_log_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`vag_id`) REFERENCES `T_vague` (`vag_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4479 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The query :

```
INSERT INTO `T_log` (
    `log_priority`,
    `log_priority_name`,
    `log_event`,
    `log_commentaire`,
    `log_impacted_row`,
    `log_duration`,
    `vag_id`
)
VALUES
    (
        6,
        "INFO",
        "TEST",
        "UPDATE",
        87552,
        "20s",
        15
    )
```

When I insert on **devsrv** :

```
Affected rows: 1
```

*(log_duration value is : `00:00:20` in Log table)*

When I insert on **qualifsrv** :

```
[Err] 1292 - Incorrect time value: '20s' for column 'log_duration' at row 1
```

**Why this difference in behavior between the two servers ?**

Comment: Care to show your insert queries, and what your time values look like?

Comment: MySQL time format is `'HH:MM:SS'` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html so your `"20s"` is an incorrect value, as it should be `"00:00:20"`

Comment: Yes you right, but how can you explain that MySQL on **devsrv** insert `"20s"` as `"00:00:20"` with no error ?

Comment: Looking at the 3rd paragraph on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html you might be okay with `"20"` (without the `s`), as MySQL would interpret it as `"00:00:20"`

Comment: I agree, but that doesn't explain the difference in behavior between the two servers ? Why one would interpret the value `"20s"` in `"00:00:20"` and not the other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the difference. It is because of the globale variable **sql_mode** that was configured to not allow other value than the one expected by the field.

More informations here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html